# Multiplicar numeros negativos sin * en java

Tags: java, operador

me gustaria saber como podria multiplicar numeros negativos en java sin usar el operador *.

```
    int finalValue= 0;
    public int product(int leftFactor, int rightFactor) {
            for(int i=1; i<=rightFactor; i++){
                finalValue += leftFactor; 
            }
            return finalValue;
        
    }
```

De esta manera puedo multiplicar los numeros pero solo si los dos son positivos pero en caso de que alguno de los dos valores sea negativo o bien ambos, el bucle no funciona.

Comment: Pues sería un caso más del if, validando cuál es positivo y cuál no, ¿no?

Comment: Nono, osea obviamente lo entra en el bucle porq el if se lo impide, lo q me gustaria saber es como puedo(quitando el if) hacer q el bucle for funcione para cualquier numero

Comment: el bucle funciona.. la multiplicacion, da lo mismo sin importar los signos.. el tema, es el signo final... la multiplicacion siempre se hace entre positivos... luego, el resultado depende de si alguno era negativo o no....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jugando con los signos de los operadores puedes hacer hacer una multiplicación normal y dependiendo del signo de cada operador al resultado le otorgas un signo u otro.

```
public static int product(int leftFactor, int rightFactor) {
    int finalValue= 0;
    if(leftFactor>0 && rightFactor>0) {
        for(int i=1; i<=rightFactor; i++){
            finalValue += leftFactor; 
        }
    }else if(leftFactor<0 && rightFactor>0){
        for(int i=1; i<=rightFactor; i++){
            finalValue += (-leftFactor); 
        }
        return -finalValue;
    }else if(leftFactor>0 && rightFactor<0){
        for(int i=1; i<= (-rightFactor); i++){
            finalValue += leftFactor; 
        }
        return -finalValue;
    }else if(leftFactor<0 && rightFactor<0){
        for(int i=1; i<= (-rightFactor); i++){
            finalValue += (-leftFactor); 
        }
    }
    return finalValue;
}
```